# Refer a custom format type in spark's DataFrameReader.format("<custom format>") using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to parse a custom format into a Dataframe in Java. I have found examples in Scala, but I'm a newbie in Spark programming and possess a very little knowledge in **Scala**. What I'm looking for is to add a custom format, in the format method of DataFrameReader.

Example code:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                                 .appName("myApp")
                                 .master("local")
                                 .getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
    .format("*com.packagename.format*") // custom format file/class
    .option("data", "data") // hint to find data from the custom format
    //many other options    
    .load(*filePath*); //file Path of the file.
```

How do I bind the *sparkcontext* to my very own custom class containing the format definitions. Also the override the load method.
Is there any possible way in java?

Using java8 and spark 2.1.0

Comment: did you get any help?

Comment: Not from here though! but got it working.

Comment: Can you post the solution here? It will be helpful.

Comment: The class you want to make as a datasource, will have to extend spark's class BaseRelation and implement Serializable, Table Scan. Then load directly the datasource as usual using Spark Context.